# Building AR(1) model using statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, statsmodels

I tried building an AR(1) model using `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA`.
My code is as following -

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA
model_ar=ARMA(df['market_value'],order=(1,0))
results_ar=model_ar.fit()
results_ar.summary()
```

These are my results-
[Initial model results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ych8T.png)

Subsequently, I tried building the same model using `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA`. My code is as following-

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
new_model_ar=ARIMA(df['market_value'],order=(1,0,0))
new_results_ar=new_model_ar.fit()
new_results_ar.summary()
```

However, this time I got slightly different results (for example, the value of the constant term is different)-
[Model results using different method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJFZD.png)

How do I make sure that running the model through the second method yields the same results as running the model through the first method? What am I missing?

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Your AR coef is (very) close to 1. DId you perform stationnary tests ?

Comment: Hi @ce.teuf, I assure you that the series is not stationary. The issue here is that theoretically ARMA(1,0) is the same as ARIMA(1,0,0), but running the model using the two methodologies gives me different results. Ideally they should return the same result. So I am wondering if there are parameters which I need to modify while running the model using the second methodology. Kindly help. Thanks!